# Google Classroom API 401 Error

Tags: javascript, google-api, oauth-2.0, service-accounts, google-classroom

I am trying to create a Google Classroom course using the Google Classroom API and a service account. I am currently experimenting using JavaScript and I have everything set up and working to get a list of course. I set up a JWT and request an authentication token which I receive.

```
{"access_token":"----ACCESS TOKEN HERE----------","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

When I use this to retrieve a user's course list (via GET) there is no problem. I receive back a proper response with a list of courses which I then display in a table.

When I try to use the same process to try to create a course (via POST), I get a 401 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

This is the code I use to authenticate:

```
function authenticate(callback) {
    function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
        str = JSON.stringify(str);
        return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
            }));
        }           


    // constuct the JWT
    var jwtHeader = {
        "alg":"RS256",
        "typ":"JWT"
    }
    jwtHeader = JSON.stringify(jwtHeader);

    //construct the Claim
    var jwtClaim = {
      "iss":"psclassroomsync@psclassroomsync.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters",
      "sub":"myemail@address.com", //this is an admin account I shouldn't really need this but tried with and without it
      "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
      "exp":(Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) + 60 * 10),
      "iat":Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
    }
    jwtClaim = JSON.stringify(jwtClaim);

    //construct the signature
    var key="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----Removed-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    var jwtSign = b64EncodeUnicode(jwtSign);
    var sJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", jwtHeader, jwtClaim, key);

    var jwt = jwtHeader + "." + jwtClaim + "." + sJWT;

    //request Token
    var grantType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";
    var tokenRequest = "grant_type=" + grantType + "&assertion=" + sJWT;
    var postURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    request = $j.ajax({
        url: postURL,
        type: "post",
        data: tokenRequest,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

This is the code I use to GET the course list.  (this works)

```
    $j("#getClasses").click(function(event){
    function getClasses(callback){
        authenticate(function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var access_token = data["access_token"];
            var apiUrl = 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses'
            var myData = 'teacherId=~(teacheremail)&access_token='+access_token;

            var files = $j.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: "get",
                data: myData,
                success: function (data) {
                    var retreivedClasses = JSON.stringify(data);
                    for(var i = 0; i < data['courses'].length; i++){
                        nextObject = data['courses'];
                        $j('#classListTable').append('<tr><td>' + nextObject[i]['name'] + '</td><td>' + nextObject[i]['courseState'] + '</td><td>' + nextObject[i]['enrollmentCode'] + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                    //$j('#classList').text(retreivedClasses);
                }
            });
        });
    }
getClasses();
});
```

This is the code that I use to create a course via POST. I've hard coded a few of the variables for testing but still gives the 401 error.

```
$j("#createClass").click(function(event){
    function createClass(callback){
        authenticate(function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var access_token = data["access_token"];
            var tokenInfo = $j.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo',
                type: 'get',
                data: "access_token="+access_token
            });
            var apiUrl = 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses'
            var myData =    'access_token='+access_token + '&ownerId=myemail@address.com&name=myClass'

            console.log(myData);
            var newGoogleClassroom = $j.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: "post",
                data: myData,
                success: function (data) {
                    var apiResponse = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $j('#classCreated').text(apiResponse);
                    }
            });
        });
    };
createClass();
});
```

Finally, this is what I get when I get the token info. It looks fine to me i.e. proper scopes: (but I am new at this)

```
{
 "azp": "removed",
 "aud": "removed",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom
.rosters",
 "exp": "1474512198",
 "expires_in": "3600",
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

I'd be grateful for any help.
Doug

P.S. I get the security implications of this code. It is in a secure environment for experimentation only. It won't see the light of day.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-manager/3-OaEKSri7Q) which is also receiving a 401 error, try to revoke the old oauth. As stated in this [related thread](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Getting-401-Error-Unauthenication/td-p/559021#), the 401 Unauthorized error you experienced may be related to [OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) using the [OAuth 2.0 client ID](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#get-an-oauth-20-client-id).

[Suggested action:](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) Refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct through the OAuth flow.